How to create an Employee Hierarchy
I created an employee hierarchy component with hard-coded data that works as it should. However, I am finding it difficult to transform fetched data to work with the component. How can I resolve this issue?
const hardcodedData = [
  {
    id: "1",
    name: "OG  UCHE  HTA",
    avatar: "https://via.placeholder.com/150",
    reportTo: ["2"],
    directReports: ["3", "4"],
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    name: "AYO  KOL ODUN",
    avatar: "https://via.placeholder.com/150",
    reportTo: [],
    directReports: ["1"],
  },
  {
    id: "3",
    name: "OLA DEB UNDE",
    avatar: "https://via.placeholder.com/150",
    reportTo: ["1"],
    directReports: [],
  },
  {
    id: "4",
    name: "ALE  US  ONY ",
    avatar: "https://via.placeholder.com/150",
    reportTo: ["1"],
    directReports: [],
  },
  {
    id: "5",
    name: "JANE DOE",
    avatar: "https://via.placeholder.com/150",
    reportTo: ["2"],
    directReports: ["6"],
  },
  {
    id: "6",
    name: "JOHN SMITH",
    avatar: "https://via.placeholder.com/150",
    reportTo: ["5"],
    directReports: [],
  },
];

const EmployeeNode = ({ employee, allEmployees }) => {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

  const handleToggle = () => {
    setOpen(!open);
  };

  const getEmployeesByIds = (ids) => {
    return ids.map((id) => allEmployees.find((emp) => emp.id === id));
  };

  return (
    <Card variant="outlined" sx={{ mb: 2 }}>
      <Box sx={{ display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center' }}>
        <ListItem>
          <ListItemAvatar>
            <Avatar src={employee.avatar} alt={employee.name} />
          </ListItemAvatar>
          <ListItemText primary={employee.name} />
          {(employee.reportTo.length > 0 || employee.directReports.length > 0) && (
            <IconButton onClick={handleToggle}>
              {open ? <ExpandLessIcon /> : <ExpandMoreIcon />}
            </IconButton>
          )}
        </ListItem>
      </Box>
      <Collapse in={open} timeout="auto" unmountOnExit>
        <CardContent sx={{ pl: 4 }}>
          {employee.reportTo.length > 0 && (
            <Box>
              <Typography variant="h6">Reports To</Typography>
              {getEmployeesByIds(employee.reportTo).map((reportToEmployee) => (
                <EmployeeNode key={reportToEmployee.id} employee={reportToEmployee} allEmployees={allEmployees} />
              ))}
            </Box>
          )}
          {employee.directReports.length > 0 && (
            <Box>
              <Typography variant="h6">Direct Reports</Typography>
              {getEmployeesByIds(employee.directReports).map((directReportEmployee) => (
                <EmployeeNode key={directReportEmployee.id} employee={directReportEmployee} allEmployees={allEmployees} />
              ))}
            </Box>
          )}
        </CardContent>
      </Collapse>
    </Card>
  );
};

export default function EmployeeHierarchy() {
  const [employeeData, setEmployeeData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    // In a real scenario, you would fetch this data from an API
    setEmployeeData(hardcodedData);
  }, []);

  if (employeeData.length === 0) {
    return <Typography>Loading...</Typography>;
  }

  const topLevelEmployees = employeeData.filter((employee) => employee.reportTo.length === 0);

  return (
    <Box sx={{ maxWidth: 600, margin: 'auto', mt: 4 }}>
      <Typography variant="h4" gutterBottom align="center">
        Employee Hierarchy
      </Typography>
      <List>
        {topLevelEmployees.map((employee) => (
          <EmployeeNode key={employee.id} employee={employee} allEmployees={employeeData} />
        ))}
      </List>
    </Box>
  );
}

EmployeeHierarchy.propTypes = {
  fetchData: PropTypes.func,
};





After fetching data from backend , my data structure looks like :
{
  "_id": "66053e8cd2d5b61190bf0793"
  },
 
 
  "employeeName": "OG  UCHE TTA",
 
  "department": "ACCOUNTS",
  "sex": "Female",
  "wages": 0,
  "bankCode": "058",
  "accountNumber": "0514915684",
  "bankName": "GTB",
 
 
  "__v": 5,
  "createdAt": {
    "$date": "2024-03-28T09:55:25.076Z"
  },
  "updatedAt": {
    "$date": "2024-05-23T07:24:41.740Z"
  },
 
  "imagePath": "https://res.cloudinary.com/youseful-apps/image/upload/v1715018162/tpsf5qnwlx7kwfxif6gy.jpg",
  "public_id": "tpsf5qnwlx7kwfxif6gy",
  "hierarchyData": [
    {
      "name": "OG  UCHE TTA",
      "reportTo": [
        {
          "name": "NWEK OGWU",
          "_id":  "664eef393d403c0a3ddb12d8"
          }
        }
      ],
      "directReports": [
        {
          "name": "IYOWUN OLA EEZ",
          "_id": "664eef393d403c0a3ddb12d9"
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "ALEXANDER  YEKA",
          "_id":  "664eef393d403c0a3ddb12da"
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "EKWEV  JESSICA  ",
          "_id":  "664eef393d403c0a3ddb12db"
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "OLA OMOTUNDE",
          "_id":  "664eef393d403c0a3ddb12dc"
          }
        }
      ],
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "664eef393d403c0a3ddb12d7"
      }
    }
  ]
}

how do I transform my fetched data to conform with hard-coded data?  This transformation should ensure that the transformedFetchedData has the same structure as the hardcodedData, with id, name, avatar, reportTo, and directReports properties properly populated.

Could you add your code you already tried to convert the data so we can have a look at it and maybe point out whats wrong?
